# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'store' not found. 'store' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: html, django

I am trying to make a simple home page which will have a link to another page named `store.html`.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'store/home.html')

def store(request):
    return render(request, 'store/store.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name ='home'),
    path('store/', views.store, name = 'store'),
]
```

**home.html**

Here I have put `href="{% url 'home' %}"` but I found `reverse not match` error and other than everything is looking good.

```html
{% extends './base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<body>
    <h1>home</h1>
    <a class = 'btn' href="{% url 'store' %}">store</a>

</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Please help me how to use fix this to make the link so that when clicking on that it will open another page.  I am new to `django` and using `version 2.1.7`.

Comment: `name` ambiguity` should be avoided. You have `app_name` and `path name` as a `store` which should be different.

Comment: Try `<a class = 'btn' href="{% url 'store:store' %}">store</a>`

Comment: ok thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error suggests, store is not a valid view function, because you have added app_name in your urls.py,

```
<body>
    <h1>home</h1>
    <a class = 'btn' href="{% url 'store:store' %}">store</a>
</body>
```

Url will always need app_name when you have mentioned it in the urlpatterns. To learn more chack [Django Namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

Comment: @BikiDeka You can mark this answer as correct for others future reference.